# Add custom function to a theme with child theme's functions.php

Tags: functions, child-theme

I am using a theme [Indigo](http://www.vivathemes.com/indigo/) and have it working fine, in a child theme configuration. I want to add a custom function. Unlike the child style.css, I have read that you don't need to import the parent functions.php. However when I add my own function to a blank file, functions.php in the child theme folder, my page doesn't load correctly and I see text from the child functions.php.

I have seen solutions on here requiring that the parent functions.php has functions that can be rewritten.

What are my options here? I want my customizations, but I don't want a theme update to bork them.

This is what I'm trying to drop in...

```
/**
 * Disable admin bar on the frontend of your website
 * for subscribers.
 */
function themeblvd_disable_admin_bar() { 
    if( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') )
        add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themeblvd_disable_admin_bar' );

/**
 * Redirect back to homepage and not allow access to 
 * WP admin for Subscribers.
 */
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;       
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );
```

It's supposed to disable the WP admin bar for low level logins.

FYI I have tested them in the parent functions.php

Comment: May be PHP tag is missing. Add `<?php` in top of file.

Comment: Indeed there were none. But when I added the tags the site loads as a blank page :/ (I put opening and closing in)

Comment: Set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php file. This will tell you exactly what your error is.

Comment: That didn't do anything, but I noticed I also had the custom functions in the parent theme functions.php still. Now the page loads OK but a few features of the template don't work :/ For example the social media links are missing, as is the logo and navigation menu.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I think adding the php tag and removing the test functions from the parent file fixed it. I just had to add some customisations to the template through the dashboard again as they were lost when I switched to the child theme.

Comment: Might it be because you are missing your '{}'-thigies on your first if statement?

Comment: @square_eyes If you solved your issue, can you write an answer so that others who share your issue can find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your choice of hook and conditional statement. Try init and remove the !.

```
function themeblvd_disable_admin_bar() { 
    if( current_user_can('edit_posts') )
        add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'themeblvd_disable_admin_bar' );
```

Looks like your conditional is also wrong for the redirect

```
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;       
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );
```

**If these snippets work as tested please mark this answer as accepted and up vote using the arrows to the left. Thanks**

Comment: Should the ! not stay because I want the admin bar removed if the logged in user can't edit posts.

Comment: ! is the the logical operator for Not so you decide.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to stop subscribers from seeing the Admin Bar and setup a redirect should they try to access the Admin Area.

```
//remove wp-admin access and remove admin bar from everyone who can't edit posts

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_posts') && !is_admin()) {
     add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_admin_bar');

function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && 
    ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
```